# WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1006

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I am connecting to a websocket client and subscribing to some streams. But I keep on getting this error

```
"'WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason'"
```

I don't know the reason. Googled the problem but no help. 
I am using websockets package. Below is my code.

```
async def streaming_data(url):
    headers = await gives_auth(auth_url)
    print(headers)
    try:
        async with websockets.client.connect(url,extra_headers=headers) as websocket:
            response = await websocket.recv()
            print(response)
    except websockets.exceptions.InvalidHandshake:
        print('Exception raised when a handshake request or response is invalid.')
    except websockets.exceptions.InvalidURI:
        print('Exception raised when an URI isn’t a valid websocket URI.')
    except websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode:
        print('Handshake responce status code is invalid')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in making the Websocket Connection!!')
        print(e.args)



loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
stream_url=""
streams = [loop.create_task(streaming_data(stream_url))]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(streams))
```

I am fairly new to this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`1006` is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
 `Close` *control frame* by an endpoint.

It is designated for use in
applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or
receiving a `Close` *control frame*.